# Move data from rows to colums VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report, where there are session names assigned to email addresses. If there are two session names assigned to an email address that generated two rows in the report, I would like to create a report where there is only one row for each email address and the session names are stored in columns adjacent to each other.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Session()
i = Sheets(1).Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
l = Sheets(2).Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For k = 2 To i
    For x = 2 To l
    EmailReg = Sheets(1).Range("c" & k).Value
    EmailAtt = Sheets(2).Range("c" & x).Value

    c = Sheets(1).Range("b" & k).Value
    d = Sheets(2).Range("A" & x).Value


        If EmailReg = EmailAtt Then
           Sheets(1).Range("D" & k).Value = Sheets(2).Range("D" & x).Value
           Sheets(2).Range("c" & x).Value = ""
        End If
        If EmailReg = EmailAtt Then
           Sheets(1).Range("E" & k).Value = Sheets(2).Range("D" & x).Value
           Sheets(2).Range("c" & x).Value = ""
        End If
        If EmailReg = EmailAtt Then
           Sheets(1).Range("f" & k).Value = Sheets(2).Range("D" & x).Value
           Sheets(2).Range("c" & x).Value = ""
        End If
        If EmailReg = EmailAtt Then
           Sheets(1).Range("g" & k).Value = Sheets(2).Range("D" & x).Value
           Sheets(2).Range("c" & x).Value = ""
        End If
        If EmailReg = EmailAtt Then
           Sheets(1).Range("h" & k).Value = Sheets(2).Range("D" & x).Value
           Sheets(2).Range("c" & x).Value = ""
        End If
        If EmailReg = EmailAtt Then
           Sheets(1).Range("i" & k).Value = Sheets(2).Range("D" & x).Value
           Sheets(2).Range("c" & x).Value = ""
        End If
        If EmailReg = EmailAtt Then
           Sheets(1).Range("j" & k).Value = Sheets(2).Range("D" & x).Value
           Sheets(2).Range("c" & x).Value = ""
        End If

    Next
Next
End Sub
```

It only puts the last session name in the different columns, so it's not working as desired.

The input looks like this:

```
  ___ A ____|___ B ____
1 | email1  | session1 
2 | email1  | session2 
3 | email1  | session3 
4 | email2  | session1 
5 | email2  | session2
```

The output should look like this:

```
  ___ A ____|___ B ____|___ C ____|___ D ____
1 | email1  | session1 | session2 | session3 
2 | email2  | session1 | session2 |
```

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3358-excel-transpose-unique-values.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with this in *sheet2*:

[image]

and run this macro:

```
Sub ReArrange()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    Set sh1 = Sheets(1)
    Set sh2 = Sheets(2)
    sh1.Cells(1, 1) = sh2.Cells(1, 1)
    sh1.Cells(1, 2) = sh2.Cells(1, 2)
    k = 3
    j = 1

    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        If sh2.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        If sh2.Cells(i, 1) = sh2.Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            sh1.Cells(j, k) = sh2.Cells(i, 2)
            k = k + 1
        Else
            j = j + 1
            sh1.Cells(j, 1) = sh2.Cells(i, 1)
            sh1.Cells(j, 2) = sh2.Cells(i, 2)
            k = 3
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

You will get this in *sheet1*:

[image]

This code does **not** erase the original data.  You may need to update this to accommodate headers, etc.